# Getting array from remote server location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

I am having one executable URL ..when I hit that URL using GET type request that URL should return me Array in Javascript...

I have created one doGet()  in remote server which returns JSON.stringfy(array);
I tried this code...can anyone tells me how I can get that array?

```
fetch(myUrl,{method:'get',headers:{'content-type'-'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
mode:'no-cors'}).then(function (response){ console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [CORS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) to read data from a different origin so **do not** set `mode:'no-cors'`.

If you are writing an extension page — [not a content extension script](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) — such as a background page, popup, or options page then you can [request cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr#requesting-permission):

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions
>   section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to
>   remote servers outside of its origin.
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "My extension",
>   ...
>   "permissions": [
>     "https://www.google.com/"
>   ],
>   ...
> }
> ```

---

Aside: You are making a **GET** request so you have no request body and so shouldn't describe the type of content in the request body. `'content-type'-'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` is nonsense.

Comment: okay thanks, @Quentin... I  am writing this code in content.js for chrome extension ....after removing mode:'no-cors' and 'content-type' - 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  where can I find that array...do I need to use any other methods to retrieve that array?

Comment: Assuming you aren't getting any errors, and assuming that the response is formatted as JSON, then you just need to parse it [as per pretty much any tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#fetch)

Comment: when I am using  JSON.parse(response); it is giving me error

Comment: @VincentB — Because the response object isn't a string representation of the body. Look at the example I linked to. Also "an error" is unhelpful. Quote error messages.